# Store channel id with command

Tags: node.js, database, discord, discord.js, command

I'm working on a discord.js v13 bot and I want to make a commmand that stores the channel id the command sent in then, A command that works only the channels stored .
I want an example of the code to do this :)

I didn't try bec I can't realize how to do it :)

Comment: How do you want to store this channel id?

Comment: With a command then, another command that works with the channels stored

Comment: you can store them in a collection and the command that shows the channels just takes them from the collection and puts them in a string (you can use the map method to do it), the only thing is that the collection will reset after restarting the bot, if you want to not lose them, use a database

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy when you know how to do it actually. **You can listen on messages in different channels with:**

```html
client.on("message", (message) => {
  console.log(`Channel-ID: ${message.channel.id}`);
});
```

See the Docs: [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Message?scrollTo=channelId)

**I don't know if it works in v13 but if not try this:**

```html
client.on("message", (message) => {
  console.log(`Channel-ID: ${message.channelId}`);
});
```

**To react when a command is used:**

```html
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if(message.startsWith("!channel")){
    console.log(`Channel-ID: ${message.channelId}`);
  }
});
```